# In Azure can you create a remdiation policy to enable logging in diagnostic settings in a storage account?

Tags: azure, azure-policy

I created a policy to remediate storage accounts that don't have diagnostic settings (classic) logs enabled. However I'm getting this error:

{"code":"DeploymentFailed","message":"At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-debug for usage details.","details":[{"code":"BadRequest","message":"{\r\n \"error\": {\r\n \"code\": \"InvalidTemplate\",\r\n \"message\": \"Unable to process template language expressions for resource '/subscriptions/providers/Microsoft.Insights/diagnosticSettings/StorageLogs' at line '1' and column '429'. 'The template parameter 'logAnalytics' is not found. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-template/#parameters for usage details.'\",\r\n \"additionalInfo\": [\r\n {\r\n \"type\": \"TemplateViolation\",\r\n \"info\": {\r\n \"lineNumber\": 1,\r\n \"linePosition\": 429,\r\n \"path\": \"\"\r\n }\r\n }\r\n ]\r\n }\r\n}"}]}

```
{
    "properties": {
        "displayName": "Deploy Diagnostic Settings for Storage Accounts to Log Analytics",
        "mode": "Indexed",
        "description": "Deploys the diagnostic settings for Storage Accounts to log read/write/delete and retain logs.",
        "metadata": {
            "category": "Monitoring"
        },
        "parameters": {
            "effect": {
                "type": "String",
                "metadata": {
                    "displayName": "Effect",
                    "description": "Enable or disable the execution of the policy"
                },
                "allowedValues": [
                    "DeployIfNotExists",
                    "Disabled"
                ],
                "defaultValue": "DeployIfNotExists"
            },
            "profileName": {
                "type": "String",
                "metadata": {
                    "displayName": "Profile Name",
                    "description": "The diagnostic setting profile name"
                },
                "default": "setbypolicy_logAnalytics"
            },
            "logAnalytics": {
                "type": "String",
                "metadata": {
                    "displayName": "Log Analytics workspace",
                    "description": "Select Log Analytics workspace from dropdown list. If this workspace is outside of the scope of the assignment you must manually grant 'Log Analytics Contributor' permissions (or similar) to the policy assignment's principal ID.",
                    "strongType": "omsWorkspace",
                    "assignPermissions": true
                }
            },
            "metricsEnabled": {
                "type": "String",
                "metadata": {
                    "displayName": "Enable metrics",
                    "description": "Whether to enable metrics stream to the Event Hub - True or False"
                },
                "allowedValues": [
                    "True",
                    "False"
                ],
                "defaultValue": "False"
            },
            "logsEnabled": {
                "type": "String",
                "metadata": {
                    "displayName": "Enable logs",
                    "description": "Whether to enable logs stream to the Event Hub - True or False"
                },
                "allowedValues": [
                    "True",
                    "False"
                ],
                "defaultValue": "True"
            }
        },
        "policyRule": {
            "if": {
                "field": "type",
                "equals": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts"
            },
            "then": {
                "effect": "[parameters('effect')]",
                "details": {
                    "type": "Microsoft.Insights/diagnosticSettings",
                    "name": "[parameters('profileName')]",
                    "existenceCondition": {
                        "allOf": [
                            {
                                "field": "Microsoft.Insights/diagnosticSettings/logs.enabled",
                                "equals": "parameters('logsEnabled')"
                            },
                            {
                                "field": "Microsoft.Insights/diagnosticSettings/metrics.enabled",
                                "equals": "parameters('metricsEnabled')]"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "roleDefinitionIds": [
                        "/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/"
                    ],
                    "deployment": {
                        "properties": {
                            "mode": "Incremental",
                            "template": {
                                "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
                                "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
                                "parameters": {
                                    "resourceName": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    },
                                    "logAnaltics": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    },
                                    "location": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    },
                                    "metricsEnabled": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    },
                                    "logsEnabled": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    },
                                    "profileName": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    }
                                },
                                "variables": {},
                                "resources": [
                                    {
                                        "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/providers/diagnosticSettings",
                                        "apiVersion": "2017-05-01-preview",
                                        "name": "[concat(parameters('resourceName'), '/', 'Microsoft.Insights/', parameters('profileName'))]",
                                        "location": "[parameters('location')]",
                                        "dependsOn": [],
                                        "properties": {
                                            "workspaceId": "[parameters('logAnalytics')]",
                                            "metrics": [
                                                {
                                                    "category": "AllMetrics",
                                                    "enabled": true,
                                                    "retentionPolicy": {
                                                        "enabled": true,
                                                        "days": 365
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            ],
                                            "logs": [
                                                {
                                                    "category": "Audit",
                                                    "enabled": true
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    "category": "Requests",
                                                    "enabled": true
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    }
                                ],
                                "outputs": {}
                            },
                            "parameters": {
                                "location": {
                                    "value": "[field('location')]"
                                },
                                "resourceName": {
                                    "value": "[field('name')]"
                                },
                                "profileName": {
                                    "value": "[parameters('profileName')]"
                                },
                                "metricsEnabled": {
                                    "value": "[parameters('metricsEnabled')]"
                                },
                                "logsEnabled": {
                                    "value": "[parameters('logsEnabled')]"
                                },
                                "logAnaltics": {
                                    "value": "[parameters('logAnalytics')]"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your typos, find the `logAnaltics` in your arm template and restore them to `logAnalytics` and let me know if it works for you.

The parameter is setup correctly though and referenced too, based on the documentation, so it's most probably a typo or some such.

I already found one, there are possibly more.

Comment: Thanks! That was the problem, now I'm receiving a: {"code":"DeploymentFailed","message":"At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-debug for usage details.","details":[{"code":"BadRequest","message":"{\r\n \"code\": \"BadRequest\",\r\n \"message\": \"Subscription is not whitelisted in the private preview of diagnostic log settings for Azure resource type 'microsoft.storage/storageaccounts', feature flag: 'microsoft.insights/diagnosticsettingpreview'.\"\r\n}"}]} error. But looks like the code is good. Thanks!